# nested jquery selectors without class/id

Tags: jquery

i'm working on an already made website from other developer. In his site, he has a div with 3 a href tags but do not have id/class:

```
        <div id="Menu_1">

            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <img src="img/common/btn_1.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank>
                <img src="img/common/btn_2" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank>
                <img src="img/common/btn_3.png" alt="">
            </a>
       </div>
```

I must use jquery for his website without changing anything from his own html/css.

I try

```
$("#Menu_1 a img:first-child").click(), 
$("#Menu_1 a img:last-child").click() 
// don't know how to select the middle button
```

but none of them are working. Is there anything wrong with my nexted jquery selectors?

Comment: You can use `nth-child` https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.eq(#)` to select any element that selector returns (0 based)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wrapper a').eq(0).css('color', 'red');
  $('.wrapper a').eq(1).css('color', 'blue');
  $('.wrapper a').eq(2).css('color', 'green');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href='#'>First</a>
  <a href='#'>Second</a>
  <a href='#'>Third</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find()` function and `eq()` selector to find particular `img` like this:

```
$('#Menu_1').find('a:eq(1)').find('img');
```

Your way also works for all 3 `img` tags, but to see it working, first you would have to close the double quotes in your html after `_blank`:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, but it's not `nth-child` of the image, but of the `a` tags.

How about:

```
$("#Menu_1 a:first-child img").click()
$("#Menu_1 a:nth-child(2) img").click()
$("#Menu_1 a:last-child img").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#Menu_1 a:nth-child(2) img").click();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `nth-child` selector:

```
$("#Menu_1 a:nth-child(2) img").click()
```